# Moved VNET to a new RG but AKS still points to old RG

Tags: azure, kubernetes, networking, azure-aks

Steps to recreate:

0. Create RG "A"
1. Create VNET in RG "A"
2. Deploy AKS using VNET created in previous step
3. Move VNET from RG "A" to the RG that AKS creates(MC_RG_something_else)
4. Enter networking configs of AKS from azure portal, an error shows up specifying:
   [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMae0.png)
5. Get the JSON specs of the AKS, see that in AgentPoolProfiles array there's a line pointing to the VNET in the RG "A"

To me this seems like a bug in Azure, the move resource api should have updated the AKS with the new ID of the VNET but clearly it did not.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should not move resources manually into the MC Resource Group of AKS. This RG is tied to the lifecycle of the AKS. If your remove your AKS your VNET will now. be also removed.

From the [Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks):

> AKS automatically deletes the node resource group whenever the cluster is deleted, so it should only be used for resources that share the cluster's lifecycle

So move your VNET to any RG except the node resource group from the AKS. one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
That VNET is intended to be only for AKS, i'm aware that if i delete the AKS the MC RG will be deleted and that's the ideal scenario.